# OOP PHP - Returning $connection from functions (please see code)

Tags: php

Procedural PHP works for me, but when I try to code like I do in objective C I cannot seem to get the functions to work. I think it has something to do with my variable scope and the functions not returning any values. Where am I going wrong with my code here?

```
      <?php 

      require_once("constants.php");

      class Main {

public $menu;
public $connection;

function connectToDatabase() {
    //connect to database & check connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .      mysqli_connect_error(); }
}

function queryDatabase($select, $from) {
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT $select FROM $from");
}

function closeDatabaseConnection() {
    mysqli_close($connection);
}

function displayMenu() {

    //connect to database & check connection
    connectToDatabase();

    //get menu data
    queryDatabase(*, pages);

    //construct menu data
    echo '<ul class="mainNavigation">';
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $row['filename'] . '.php">';
            echo $row['menu_name'];
            echo '</a></li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';

    //close connection
    closeDatabaseConnection();
}

function displayFooter() {

}

function getUser() {

}

function userLogIn() {

}

  } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using $connection, you should use $this->connection, and run it like so:

```
$Db = new Main();

$Db->connectToDatabase();
```

If you want to access a property inside a method, make sure to reference it with `$this->prop`, rather than just $prop. If the method is static, use `self::prop` instead.

`$this` refers to the current instantiation of the class. You would use the scope resolution operator (`::`) if the method/property is static (`DBConnection::connection` `DBConnection::connectToDatabase()`)/

Also, I'd rename class 'Main' to something else like DBConnection (PHP doesn't use main methods like C does), then:

```
$Db = new DBConnection();
$Db->connectToDatabase();
```

Because in PHP, although you can have one class in one PHP file named connection.php, with a class of Main, if you have another class following the same pattern, then you'll have two Main classes.

Comment: Thank you Emma have tried this and like your suggestion. I also did wonder about using Main and know i know, appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use a method or variable inside it's own class, you have to put `$this->` in front of it. For exmaple this `connectToDatabase();` would become this `$this->connectToDatabase();`

Comment: Thank you for answering, i have been using $this-> in some of my classes but you both have given me the final piece to my puzzle and for that i thank you! :) Matt.

Answer (score 0):

There are all kinds of things wrong with this class, so I will focus on a few key points and maybe you can fix it from there without us having a total rewrite

First, consider this:

```
public $connection;

function connectToDatabase() {
    //connect to database & check connection
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .      mysqli_connect_error(); }
}
```

You declare a class variable $connection, which is ok. But in your function you assign a local variable instead of accessing the class variable. From within a class, you would call all class members using $this. So the function should be:

```
function connectToDatabase() {
    //connect to database & check connection
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .      mysqli_connect_error(); }
}
```

Now, other methods attempt to call functions but they need to do the same thing:

```
function displayMenu() {

    //connect to database & check connection
    // this should just check to see if $connection is populated. if not then call this method
    $this->connectToDatabase();
```

And this method is not accessing the class var for connection:

```
function queryDatabase($select, $from) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection,"SELECT $select FROM $from");
}
```

those few examples should give you the basic idea of accessing class methods and variables. You can ask specific questions and we may update, but for now this should get you going.

Comment: Thank you for answering, i have been using $this-> in some of my classes but you both have given me the final piece to my puzzle and for that i thank you! :) Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a mysqli connection class that I use regularly. It might not answer your question but you can study it and it should help you better understand the concept. It did for me anyway.

```
class DBConnection  
{       
    protected $mysqli;
    private  $db_host='localhost';
    private  $db_name='';
    private  $db_username='';
    private  $db_password='';

    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_username,
        $this->db_password, $this->db_name) or die($this->mysqli->error);

        return $this->mysqli;
    }

    public function getLink() {
        return $this->mysqli;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        return $this->mysqli->query($query);
     }

    public function real_escape_string($str) {
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($str);
    }

    function __destruct(){
        $this->mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

And then when you need to connect to the database in another class call it in the construct function like so:

```
public function __construct(DBConnection $mysqli) {
    $this->mysqli = $mysqli->getLink();
}
```